# How to Import stylesheets in xslt conditionally?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there any way to import stylesheets after checking some conditions?

Like,if the value of variable $a="1" then import 1.xsl or else import 2.xsl.

Answer (score 17):

> Hi All, Is there any way to import
>   stylesheets after checking some
>   conditions?
>
> Like,if the value of variable $a="1"
>   then import 1.xsl or else import
>   2.xsl.

**No, the `<xsl:import>` directive is only compile-time**.

In XSLT 2.0 one can use the **[`use-when`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conditional-inclusion)** attribute for a limited conditional compilation.

**For example**:

```
<xsl:import href="module-A.xsl" 
     use-when="system-property('xsl:vendor')='vendor-A'"/>
```

The limitations of the `use-when` attribute are that there is no dynamic context when the attribute is evaluated -- in particular that means that there are no in-scope variables defined.

**A non-XSLT solution** is to dynamically change the `href` attribute of the `<xsl:import>` declaration before the transformation is invoked:

1. Parse the xsl stylesheet as an XML file
2. Evaluate the condition that determines which stylesheet should be imported.
3. Set the value of the `href` attribute of the `<xsl:import>` declaration to the URI of the dynamically determined stylesheet-to-be-imported.
4. Invoke the transformation with the in-memory xsl stylesheet that was just modified.

Comment: +1 usefull answer something i've been thinking about! and im sure others with be curious at some point

Comment: +1 Good answer. It makes no sense to espect that `xsl:import` or `xsl:include` work different than other language's instructions like `import` or `#include`. Also, because the `xsl:import/@href` it's a URI, that resource could also be built dynamicly (with almost the same restrictions of `@use-when`)

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old, but I want to share my opinion.

Each display could use one template instead of two. The value display will be change with a VB application.

`breakfast_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="conditionDisplay.xsl" ?>
<data>
    <breakfast_menu>
        <food>
            <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$5.95</price>
            <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
            <calories>650</calories>
        </food>

        <food>
            <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
            <price>$7.95</price>
            <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
            <calories>900</calories>
        </food>


        <food>
            <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
            <price>$6.95</price>
            <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
            <calories>950</calories>
        </food>
    </breakfast_menu> 
    <display>1</display>
</data>
```

In this file, I imported my displays and with a condition I tell the template what I need.

`conditionDisplay.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:import href="display1.xsl"/>
    <xsl:import href="display2.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="display"><xsl:value-of select= "data/display"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$display='1'">
                <xsl:call-template name="display1" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="display2 />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`display1.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="display1">
        <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
                <xsl:for-each select="data/breakfast_menu/food">
                    <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
                        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                            <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="calories"/> calories per serving)</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`display2.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>futur
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="display2">
        <html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#222222">
                <xsl:for-each select="data/breakfast_menu/food">
                    <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
                        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
                        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
                            <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="calories"/> calories per serving)</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I genuinely apologize for my terrible English. It will be better to the next post and I hope will help someone as I think it's not the best solution.

Comment: I've done something similar with modes. Good first answer. +1 Welcome to stackoverflow!